# viewBinding not work in android studio.what is problem?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

When I use view binding and call a view with it
And I handle an event and run the program when I click on the view to test it nothing happens

there is no error

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this))

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //Test view binding
        binding.btnOneNumber.setOnClickListener { 
            binding.txtView.text = "1"
        }

    }
}
```

this is my build.gradle

```
android{
  buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setup of viewbinding in the onCreate method is what's causing the problem see - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#activities for reference.
It is best practice to declare your binding variable above onCreate as a latinit like this - `private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding` Then you should set the binding variable inside onCreate to the binding class being inflated - `binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)` Afterwards get the root view  - `val view = binding.root` - and use that instead to set the content view
`setContentView(view)` Overall you code should look like this

> class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)

    //Test view binding
    binding.btnOneNumber.setOnClickListener { 
        binding.txtView.text = "1"
    }

}
```

}

Your app wasn't responding before because you were setting the wrong view to be your layout, with the code I've shown you're setting the view associated with the binding to be your layout which is why the binding becomes responsive.

Answer (score 0):

when you are using binding

```
    val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this))
```

then you must use its root as content view, so

```
setContentView(binding.root)
```

Answer (score 0):

enable databinding feature as below

```
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
```

don't incude `<layout> </layout>` in your xml

access like below

```
 val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this))
 setContentView(binding.root)
```